# Wireless Presenter in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, hid

I have a Wireless Laser Presenter that works fine in every Windows version except for Windows 8.

Multimedia and mouse functions do not work under this OS. However, the page up and down functions work, so it is not a connectivity problem.

In the Windows drivers section I can see that there are 2 conflicts. The device has no driver available and it is USB plug and play.

Presenter errors:

[image]

I tried a driver from a different manufacturer: [Logitech driver for Windows 7](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-presenter-r400?section=downloads&bit=&osid=14), and I was able to use the multimedia and mouse functions. Unfortunately, I was not able to repeat the process and it worked only one time. Nevertheless, that proved me that it is possible to make the Wireless Presenter work under Windows 8.

I need to know if someone has a Wireless Presenter working in Windows 8, or how can I make it work. It seems a simple HID device, so I do not understand why Windows 7 recognizes it but Windows 8 don't.

[This is the device](http://www.eurocase.com/archivos/productos2/14/01_eulp_24_grande.jpg).

Comment: I also have made a post in [Windows 8.1 Forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8b1e3869-b91d-4c1f-bd80-2d4cb5c52393/wireless-presenter-in-windows-8?forum=w8itprohardware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It seems to be a Windows issue.

From the **Device Manager**, I access to the two items with problems. For each **USB input device**, I disable the controller and then enable it. By doing this, I remove the error: "This device cannot start. (Code 10)", and the device status changes to "This device is working properly".

Steps and images can be found here: [Windows forum entry](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8b1e3869-b91d-4c1f-bd80-2d4cb5c52393/wireless-presenter-in-windows-8?forum=w8itprohardware).